# How to solve cannot assign to function call in this Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, linear-regression

```
#Start cleaning loop through all the pings
for P in Pings:
    
    #All beams for current ping
    print("Cleansing completed", round(P/len(Pings)*100,1),"%")
    
    Slice_one = df[(df.P==P)&(df.Bm>0)&(df.Bm<257)].copy()
    
    model = LinearRegression().fit(Slice_one.Bm.values.reshape((-1,1)), Slice_one.Z.values)
    
    Slice_one["Z_1"] = model.predict(Slice_one.Bm.values.reshape((-1,1)))
    
    Slice_one("dZ") = abs(Slice_one.Z_1 - Slice_one.Z)
    
    Slice_one_Cor = Slice_one[(Slice_one.dZ < 0.4)]
    
    Slice_one_Cor.drop(["Z_1", "dZ"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    
    df_Clean = pd.concat([df.Clean, Slice_one_cor], ignore_index = True)
```

File "", line 13
Slice_one("dZ") = abs(Slice_one.Z_1 - Slice_one.Z)
^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: change it to  `Slice_one["dZ"] = abs(Slice_one.Z_1 - Slice_one.Z)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use square brackets [ ], `Slice_one["dZ"] = abs(Slice_one.Z_1 - Slice_one.Z)`